# Why does (or <falsey value> <falsey value>) return the final value in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, boolean

I'm getting started with Clojure and noticed that though Clojure's `or` behavior is said to return the first truthy value, passing two falsey values to `or` returns simply the second value:

```
user=> (or false false)
false

user=> (or false nil)
nil
```

My experience is primarily in Python, where

```
>>> False or False
False
```

Are these not analogous? I understand this is the expected behavior per http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/or and followed the suggestion to look into http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/if, but remain unclear on why it's so.

Comment: Eh, in Python you use `or`, not `|`. `|` is bitwise. `or` in Python behaves like `or` in Clojure (unfortunately).

Comment: Right, that was sloppy. Thank you!

Comment: I just noticed the "boolean" tag here - `or` in clojure is in no way boolean

Comment: I can't think of anything in the falsey cases, but for truthy values there are idioms like `... (let x [or x default-value-for-x] body-using-x)...` that depend on `or` returning the value of the expression instead of a `true`.

Answer (score 5):

I think the doc string makes it clear. It never promises to return false - merely to return the last argument if no others remain.

```
user=> (doc or)
-------------------------
clojure.core/or
([] [x] [x & next])
Macro
  Evaluates exprs one at a time, from left to right. If a form
  returns a logical true value, or returns that value and doesn't
  evaluate any of the other expressions, otherwise it returns the
  value of the last expression. (or) returns nil.
nil
```

Also, I don't know where you got the idea that `or` takes two arguments.

```
user=> (or nil false false false 1 (println "this is not printed"))
1
user=> (or nil false)
false
user=> (or true)
true
user=> (or)
nil
```

Comment: Thank you -- I just missed that because I was looking for a different description (like why this is the case).

I don't think `or` takes two arguments, but used that example for simplicity.

Comment: Generalized `or` with short circuiting and arbitrary argument count dates back to the ancient history of lisp, it's still around because it is useful.

Comment: My confusion arises in part from not knowing how I could differentiate between scenarios where the last argument is returned because it is true and where it is returned because it is the last.

Comment: The last argument is never returned because it is true. If you look at the source, if there is one argument left, that one is always evaluated and returned.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it does this because it's faster.

Remember that `or` is a macro that constructs a cascade of `if` forms *at compile time*, terminating, when it gets down to one argument, in (constructing a form) just returning that argument.

For example,

```
(or 1 2 3)
```

... expands into something equivalent to

```
(if 1 1 (if 2 2 3))
```

If we include the jiggery-pokery that makes sure that the expressions are evaluated only once, the expansion looks more like this:

```
(let [__auto__ 1]
  (if __auto__
    __auto__
    (let [__auto__ 2]
      (if __auto__
        __auto__
        3))))
```

... where `__auto__` is some symbol that won't collide with any used in the arguments to `or`.

You can find the full story in the [source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L813).

Answer (score 0):

Actually a lot of languages behaves the same like javascript, php and python. It's even a convention in javascript to provide default values to function arguments `myval = myval or defaultValue;`. And in php people write something like `do_something() or die();`. `or` is simply not just for booleans in dynamic languages. It also took me a long time to realize that.